# count number of times a date is shown in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of dates in a column in Excel and would like to show a total for each unique date.

So say this is the original list:

```
03/05/2019
03/05/2019
03/05/2019
03/05/2019
03/05/2019
07/05/2019
07/05/2019
07/05/2019
08/05/2019
08/05/2019
08/05/2019
09/05/2019
09/05/2019
```

I'd like to convert that to this:

```
03/05/2019,5
07/05/2019,3
08/05/2019,3
09/05/2019,2
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to get a column consisting of unique values. This can be done following this:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2

or if you want to manually use equations,

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/21/get-list-unique-values-excel/

Then, to get the actual counts of those unique values, you can use `=COUNTIF()`. So say your original list is in `A1:A13` and the unique values are in `B1:B4`. You would do `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$13,B1)` in `B1`, and copy/paste that to `B2`, `B3` and `B4`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to actually have each unique value with it's count in one cell seperated with a comma you could try this rather long formula:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=TEXT(INDEX($A$1:$A$13,SMALL(INDEX((MATCH($A$1:$A$13&"",$A$1:$A$13&"",0)<>ROW($A$1:$A$13))*10^10+ROW($A$1:$A$13),0),ROW(1:1))),"dd/mm/yyyy")&","&COUNTIF($A$1:$A$13,INDEX($A$1:$A$13,SMALL(INDEX((MATCH($A$1:$A$13&"",$A$1:$A$13&"",0)<>ROW($A$1:$A$13))*10^10+ROW($A$1:$A$13),0),ROW(1:1))))
```

Drag down...

---

Hindsight, your requirement was different but i'll leave the other option there for future reference. With headers and a column for unique values and another one for the appropriate count see example below:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$14,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$14),0),0))
```

Formula in `D2`:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14,C2)
```

Drag both down...

Comment: CSE formula or standard?

Comment: @ForwardEd just standard would do

Comment: Thanks JvdV, I think this is close to what I'm after. However, what I should have said in my example is that the comma is another column. So the values after the comma in your screenshot would go into column D. Would that also reduce the complexity of the formula? Your is an impressive beast!

Comment: @Wes it would drastically change the formula. Do you also have headers? Or would your data start at row one

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear before. Yes, there would be headers.

Comment: @Wes, see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with formulas, and would probably want that if your data is dynamic and you want the result to be automatically updated.  Otherwise, I agree with Scott Craner's comment about using a pivot table.  You can get your result with a few clicks of the mouse.

[image]

You'll want a column heading.  You just select the data and then insert a pivot table from the menu or toolbar.  Drag the column heading to the Rows window and to the Values window (and verify that the aggregation method selected is Count).  There are a couple of administrative selections, like where to stick the pivot table, and whether to include a grand total.

And you're done.

Comment: I'd forgotten about pivots, my Excel is extremely rusty! Thank you, this also works well.